# 6003 Sinch - React Js

Tags: javascript, sinch

[here is image for console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnXjN.png)"No valid identity or authentication ticket"

I am getting this error on starting the sinch client.

```
 var handleFail = function () { console.log("fail") }
 const signUpObject = { "userId": 302 }       
 sinchClient.start(signUpObject).then(sinchClient.start.bind(sinchClient)).then(handleSuccess).fail(handleFail)
```

Comment: Please add more details so we can help

Answer (score 1):

As it says that is not a valid ticket, you need to sign in our your backend with secret for you app.
https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/javascript/#authentication

Comment: In my case even if we have the Application Key and Secret the ticket is not being accepted by Sinch, we are using the https://github.com/sinch/servlet-javascript-authentication as example